# Image resizing with GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm really trying to nail out a little more performance out of this tidbit of code. It's not a heavly used bit of code but is used every time a new image is uploaded, and 4 times for each image (100px, 200px, 500px, 700px). So when there are any more than 2 or 3 images processing, it gets a little busy on the server. Also I'm trying to figure out how to make it correctly process images with a low resolution. Currently it just chops it off half way through, not plesent.
Examples: [Original](http://timmeers.net/Original/626), [large](http://timmeers.net/large/626), [xLarge](http://timmeers.net/xlarge/626)

```
public static byte[] ResizeImageFile(byte[] imageFile, int targetSize)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFile)))
    {
        Size newSize = CalculateDimensions(oldImage.Size, targetSize);

        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
        {
            newImage.SetResolution(oldImage.HorizontalResolution, oldImage.VerticalResolution);
            using (Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                canvas.DrawImage(oldImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize));
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                newImage.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return m.GetBuffer();
            }
        }

    }
}

private static Size CalculateDimensions(Size oldSize, int targetSize)
{
    Size newSize = new Size();
    if (oldSize.Width > oldSize.Height)
    {
        newSize.Width = targetSize;
        newSize.Height = (int)(oldSize.Height * (float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Width);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize.Width = (int)(oldSize.Width * (float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Height);
        newSize.Height = targetSize;
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Thanks for and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thought that comes to mind is, have you thought about Multithreading it? i.e. calling this method for each image (or batch of images) in a separate thread? That way, if your server has a few cores you can get things done quicker. Just a thought...

Comment: Besides multi-threading, I will also add caching & leverage file system (rather than db).

Comment: @Jay Zeng, currently the app is processing the images prior to inserting them into a database. A little caching might go a long way, but I'll have to do a lot more testing to make sure it's not going to affect to much and limit my 6gb of memory even further.

Comment: I like the idea of threading. I should be able to pop it into a new thread, this should speed up the overall view of the site when one user is uploading a lot of files and others are trying to view the rest of the site. I'll get cracking on this tonight! Now any idea on how to make it work better for lower resolution images?

Comment: I've added an example as well of the second issue.

Answer (score 1):

(Threading is a great tip.)

Try to call your method with the smallest possible image as input each time, instead of the original image. If the original image is, say 2000px, then create the 700px image from it and then use your newly created 700px image to create the 500px, etc...

With the HighQualityBicubic setting I doubt that you'll notice any difference in the 100px image. (But it of course it needs to be verified.)

Comment: I love this idea! I never really thought about in that way either, to me it's like doing it backwards. I normally don't think backwards (despite what my coworkers think). This combined with threading should be a huge help as then it wont have to reprocess the 2 to 4mb file for each image size. I'll test and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is the solution to the second part of the question which was never answered. When processing a low resolution image the image was being cut off. The solution now, seems obvious. The problem lies in this bit of code from above:

```
using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, 
                                                    PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
```

The problem being that I'm selecting the PixelFormat, not letting it be the format of the original image. The correct code is here:

```
public static byte[] ResizeImageFile(byte[] imageFile, int targetSize)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFile)))
    {
        Size newSize = CalculateDimensions(oldImage.Size, targetSize);

    using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height,  
                                                        oldImage.PixelFormat))
    {
        newImage.SetResolution(oldImage.HorizontalResolution, 
                                                   oldImage.VerticalResolution);
        using (Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            canvas.DrawImage(oldImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize));
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            newImage.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return m.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

   }
}
```