# How can I get better results when shrinking an image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm scaling images down in c#, and I've compared my methods with the best method in Photoshop cs5 and cannot replicate it.

In PS i'm using bicubic sharper, which looks really good. However, when trying to do the same in c# I don't get as high quality results. I've tried bicubic interpolation as well as HQ bicubic, smoothing mode HQ/None/AA. Composition modes, I've tried about 50 different variations and each one comes out pretty close to the image on the right.

You'll notice the pixelation on her back and around the title, as well as the authors name not coming out too well.

(Left is PS, right is c#.)

[image]

It seems that c# bicubic does too much smoothing even with smoothing set to none. I've been playing around with many variations of the following code:

```
 g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
 g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
 g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;
 g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

**Edit:** As requested here is the starting image (1mb).
[image]

Comment: A link to the original might help.

Comment: It's a very high quality jpeg, ill post it though.

Comment: The right image, the one you say is generated using C#, has JPEG compression artifacts.

Comment: @Rick, what puzzles me is why? I can't get rid of them with variations of the code above. HQ bicubic smooth's the hell out of the image, unlike photoshops version of bicubic.

Comment: @Nick: None of the interpolation modes will produce JPEG artifacts.  They are either there before the interpolation or you introduce them upon saving.

Comment: @Rick, So what am I doing wrong? In both Ps and c# im using the large image above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something, but I have typically used the following code below to resize/compress JPEG Images. Personally, I think the result turned out pretty well based on your source image. The code doesn't handle a few edge cases concerning input parameters, but overall gets the job done (I have additional extension methods for Cropping, and Combining image transformations if interested).

Image Scaled to 25% original size and using 90% Compression. (~30KB output file)

[image: SampleImage]

**Image Scaling Extension Methods:**

```
public static Image Resize(this Image image, Single scale)
{
  if (image == null)
    return null;

  scale = Math.Max(0.0F, scale);

  Int32 scaledWidth = Convert.ToInt32(image.Width * scale);
  Int32 scaledHeight = Convert.ToInt32(image.Height * scale);

  return image.Resize(new Size(scaledWidth, scaledHeight));
}

public static Image Resize(this Image image, Size size)
{
  if (image == null || size.IsEmpty)
    return null;

  var resizedImage = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, image.PixelFormat);
  resizedImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

  using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
  {
    var location = new Point(0, 0);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(location, size), new Rectangle(location, image.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  }

  return resizedImage;
}
```

**Compression Extension Method:**

```
public static Image Compress(this Image image, Int32 quality)
{
  if (image == null)
    return null;

  quality = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, quality));

  using (var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
  {
    var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(encoder => String.Compare(encoder.MimeType, "image/jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, Convert.ToInt64(quality));

    image.Save(memoryStream, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);

    return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
  using(var source = Image.FromFile(@"C:\~\Source.jpg"))
  using(var resized = source.Resize(0.25F))
  using(var compressed = resized.Compress(90))
    compressed.Save(@"C:\~\Output.jpg");
```

**NOTE:**
For anyone who may comment, you cannot dispose the MemoryStream created in the Compress method until after the image is disposed. If you reflect in to the implementation of Dispose on MemoryStream, it is actually save to not explicitly call dispose. The only alternative would be to wrap the image/memory stream in a custom implementation of a class that implements Image/IDisposable.

Comment: @Calgary, I'll go with this answer as it addresses setting the quality level, which results in exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've not tried it but am always looking for a better way to process images. But my question, how good is this for lower resolution images. My method does a terrible job with them. stackoverflow.com/q/2025240/90764

Comment: I'll be giving this method a try later tonight for sure though.

Comment: @Tim - Your link appears to be broken. As for your question, you are always going to be constrained by your source image (obviously), the above approach shouldn't result in any further degradation unless you drop the quality of the image when calling compress.

Comment: Yea thats because I failed at making it a correct link after 2 edits I gave up and just made it a copy paste required link. I'm not reducing quality at all I thought, just the size. I'll see about editing the link. edit, oops took to long [i'll try this link again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2025240/90764) (Got it!)

Comment: @Tim - Code above works fine with your sample image... if you are having specific issues, best bet it to open a new question.

Comment: @CalgaryCoder, do you have this extension method posted in it's entirety anywhere?

Comment: @Tim, no; the above code is the entire compress/resize functionality. The only additional item that I have available is basic crop support (and some hybrid extensions to combine steps). Are you looking for something in particular?

Comment: @Calgary Coder,

I have followed ur code as it is but am getting a blackish wired image. could u say what went wrong.size i gave is 100,50

Comment: @Anish I am not sure what you mean, I would suggest asking a new question with additional details.

Comment: @ Calgary Coder: I am working with a web api and am getting an image as base64 string in the request  i have to resize the image to 100by50. I have tried many code and found urs as an elegant solution but am getting the image as a black screen i havn't changed any code that of yours. only the difference is that am getting a png image.

Comment: @ Calgary Coder: I have asked a Separate question as u suggested.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140710/re-size-image-not-working-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the amount of [JPEG artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact), especially at the top of the image, I think you set the jpg compression to high. That results in a smaller (filesize) file, but reduces image quality and seems to add more blur.

Can you try saving it in a higher quality? I assume the line containing `CompositingQuality.HighQuality` does this already, but maybe you can find an even higher quality mode. What are the differences in file size between Photoshop and C#? And how does the Photoshop image look after you saved it and reopened it? Just resizing in Photoshop doesn't introduce any jpg data loss. You will only notice that after you've saved the image as jpg and then closed and reopened it.

Comment: PS is 34kb vs 21kb. The `Graphics` class has an exhaustive list of properties and methods, but I believe the 4 above are the main ones. I don't know any of getting more high quality than the HighQuality setting.

Comment: I don't know either, but the resulting image you pasted here doesn't seem to have a very high quality. In Photoshop, you got High, but also Very High. Each of this 'named' levels represent a range of actual values, where Very High means qualities of 80 to 100 and High meaning 60. I don't know how these figures translate to c#, but as you can tell, the Photoshop image is almost twice the size, so it presumably is stored with a greater quality.

Comment: @Nick - the quality is a numeric value between 0 and 100. The higher the value the less the compression and the higher the quality of the image.

Comment: I stumbled on this Q&A. Maybe it's of use to you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c

Comment: The Drawing2D class has a QualityMode proeprty too, but since it is a generic drawing class, I don't know if these properties will actually affect Jpeg compression when storing the file. It seems to me these are unrelated and the properties mentioned mainly affect on-screen rendering quality.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669850/jpeg-compression-with-high-quality-in-c)

I used this code to use no compression of the jpeg and it comes out like the PS version:

```
ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 
    ImageCodecInfo ici = null; 
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    { 
        if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg") 
            ici = codec; 
    } 

    EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(); 
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);
```

Comment: Yup, pretty much same approach as in the Compress extension method shown above. You can actually reduce image quality to 90/95 with out any notable loss in quality to reduce image size.

Comment: You can use 100L instead of (long)100 or even just 100 as the parameter. C# converts ints to long if needed and 100L is a long literal.

Comment: @Kim, Yes I knew that, do you know why it was casted to long in the first place? If it expects a number from 0-100 then int16(short) would work.